# Bootstrap button not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems a bootstrap button to work.  We are making a site that allows people to vote up or down on various items.

The vote-up button works, however the vote-down doesn't.  When I hover over the vote-down button it doesn't

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="content-left-sidebar-meta">
    <div class="post-vote-header">
        <a class="btn btn-default post-vote post-vote-up" data-post-id="90" href="http://localhost/wp/tag/top-10-fastest-cars/#vote-up" title="Like">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        <div class="vote-count">0</div>
        <a class="btn btn-default post-vote post-vote-down" data-post-id="90" href="http://localhost/wp/tag/top-10-fastest-cars/#vote-down" title="Dislike">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does `data-post-id` have the same `value` = `90`

Comment: That's what I got from the back end developer I'm working with.  Would that affect the button?

Comment: Not enough data in the question to answer.  The <a> tag in your e.g.  does not have any functionality that may lead to "not working"... is there script that is linked to this?

Comment: create fiddle or add some more detail

Comment: HTML describes what things *are*, CSS describes how things *look*, and Javascript defines what things *do*. If something is not *doing* something, check the javascript. post what javascript you're using in this question. and read Bootstrap documentation.